# Convert an array of metadata to GeoTIFF, when the array was synthesized by smaller arrays, that correspond to same size tiles of a bigger image

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, numpy

I wanted to process the metadata of an image from Google Earth Engine (python) and the image was huge, which means I could not download. For this reason and since I know the boundaries, I thought it would be a good idea to get the image in tiles with a nested `for` loop that ranges in x and y coordinates.

So I got the tiles of the image and read each tile's metadata and saved it eventually in a dataframe where index is the x coordinate and the column is the y coordinate and each element at the location [x,y] in the df is an array (0 to 255 floats) which, I suppose, correspond to each pixel of all the pixels included in the tile (x to next, y to next y / the step I am using in the for loops is 0.1).

Next, I stacked the arrays vertically and, then, horizontally and ended up with a whole array which has a shape: `(110550, 1650)` and which, theoretically and according to my rationale, corresponds to the metadata of the big image which I got looping between these limits as following:

```
x_min = 13.8
x_max = 33.809
y_min = 33.2
y_max = 43.009

range_x = np.arange(x_min, x_max, 0.1)
range_y = np.arange(y_min, y_min+0.3, 0.1)
```

Getting the info of the big image via `ee.getInfo()`, I get this profile:
[image]

So my questions are:

1. Has my rationale wrong assumptions and this is never gonna work?
2. How am I going to convert the whole array to a GeoTIFF with the provided geospatial details?

So far, I tried something along these lines but it gives the following error:

```
>>> total.shape
(110550, 1650) # this is the shape of the whole array

>>> tiff_info = {'driver'    : 'GTiff',
                'crs'       : 'EPSG:4326', # tiff_file.crs
                'height'    : total.shape[0], # number of rows
                'width'     : total.shape[1], # number of columns
                'count'     : 1, # band
                'dtype'     : total.dtype,
                'transform' : from_origin(west=x_min, # minimum x
                                          north=y_max, # maximum y
                                          xsize=250,
                                          ysize=250)
                          }

>>> import rasterio
>>> from rasterio.transform import from_origin

>>> tiff_output_path = './test_raster.tiff'

>>> with rasterio.open(tiff_output_path, 'w', **tiff_info) as dst:
        dst.write(total, 1)

>>> print(f'Geotiff has been created at {tiff_output_path}')
```

> CRSError: The WKT could not be parsed. OGR Error code 6

I can provide pieces of code if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I'm assuming you want to download the image.  If that's the case, almost surely the answer is use `Export` [python reference](https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/ee/batch.py#L169), [JavaScript reference](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/export-image-todrive).

Note that you can extract pieces of the image to some local data structure.
That is, you can request chunks of data from the Earth Engine server and have access to the data on a client machine.  In that case, I'd suggest using `getInfo()` as described in [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/intro-to-python-api#get_a_time_series).

Comment: I have already downloaded the image in tiles and saved them locally. I have also acquired the metadata of each tile, so now I have a bunch of arrays with integers from 0 to 255, which I have combined in one big array. What I am looking for is to convert the big array into a GeoTIFF which I will be able to project on a map. I know the geoprofile of the big Earth Engine image (the screenshot in my post) and I am looking into HOW I translate the big array into a GeoTIFF locally.